# Use of hashes to declare a variable in ReactJS/Javascript Es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, jsx

I would like to know the difference between:

```
const data = this.props.content;
```

And

```
const {data} = this.props.content;
```

I saw it before but declaring 3 or 4 variables all together. However I've never seen it with just 1 variable.

What's the difference?

Comment: In first case you assign to `data`  `.content`, in second case you get `data` property from `.content` and assign it to variable `data` - it is equivalent to `const data = this.props.content.data;`

Comment: Oh, I think that I got it. For example if I do: `const {content} = this.props` is equivalent at `const content=this.props.content` , right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a syntactic advantage of using the same name for your variable. It takes advantage of ES6 destructuring. I believe the example you listed should be altered slightly which illustrates and hopefully answers your question.

```
const data = this.props.content; // is exactly the same as
const {content} = this.props;
```

A nice writeup of destructuring can be found here: [Some ES6+ features used in React development](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2016/03/es6-features-used-react-development/)

Comment: No, it's **not** exactly the same. The first line defines a variable called `data`, the second line defines a variable called `content`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are setting `data` to be `this.props.content`.

Your second example is known as destructuring, which can be read about more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

You are basically creating a new variable by pulling it out of what you put on the right hand side.